# How to automate app versioning in Android

Tags: android, gradle, versioning

I have a CI tool(Bamboo) which runs my Unit Tests and builds the app-release.apk. Whenever I make changes in my app and the build in successful I create a new Version number.I store the version number and build time in a file. Can I make Gradle to read from that file and change the app version accordingly?

Content of my file looks like this:

```
ProductVersion=0.0.0.0.0
ProductBuildDateTime=2017-01-01T00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes of course, this is how I do it:

I store my versions in a version.properties file.

Then in the app's build.gradle I use the following code:

```
//Path to the file of your properties file that contains the version number
final String VERSION_PROPERTIES_FILE = projectDir.getParentFile().getParent() + "/file.properties"

 /**
 * Returns the id of the property name from config file, null if it doesn't exist
     * @param propertyName
     * @param properties file name in assets dir
     * @return
     */
    def getPropertyFromFile(propertiesFilePath, propertyName) {
        def propsFile = new File(propertiesFilePath);
        if (propsFile.canRead()) {
            def props = new Properties();
            props.load(new FileInputStream(propsFile));
            return props.getProperty(propertyName, null);
        } else {
            throw new GradleException("Could not read $propertiesFilePath !")
        }
    }

int vCode = getPropertyFromFile(VERSION_PROPERTIES_FILE, "versionCode") as Integer
String vName = getPropertyFromFile(VERSION_PROPERTIES_FILE, "versionName")

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.x.x"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode vCode
    versionName vName
}
```

In your case, you could pass `"ProductBuildDateTime"` and `"ProductVersion"` to the method that reads the file.

Comment: You don't close the file stream, so Gradle daemon will hold a lock to the file, especially on Windows. You should better do something like `new File(path).withInputStream { properties.load it }` which automatically handles stream creation and closing. This is similar to try-with-resources in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Yes

> If you meant how to do it, well simply do something like
>
> ```
> def properties = new Properties()
> def file = new File('version.properties')
> file.withInputStream {
>     properties.load it
> }
> properties.ProductVersion = ...
> properties.ProductBuildDateTime = ...
> file.withOuputStream {
>     properties.store it, true
> }
> ```

Comment: you are a real vampire!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to read build info from a file you can use a more simplified version of the given answers like this :

```
def getCIProperty(String key)
{
    Properties properties = new Properties()
    properties.load( file("Bamboo File Absolute Path").readLines().join("\n"))
    properties.getProperty(key)
}

getCIProperty('ProductVersion')
getCIProperty('ProductBuildDateTime')
```

Just copy and paste it into your main build file , not the settings.gradle file

or if you are using bamboo , you can do it more easily by just asking the bamboo to pass those properties in the build command like this:

Copy and past these codes anywhere in your build script (even in settings.gradle)

```
gradle.productVersion = getProperty('ProductVersion')
gradle.productBuildDateTime = getProperty('ProductBuildDateTime')
```

and now simply ask bamboo to add these two arguments to the build command like so:

```
gradle -PProductVersion=0.0.0.0.0   -PProductBuildDateTime=2017-01-01T00:00:00.000   clean   assembleRelease
```

Tip: clean and assembleRelease are tasks in the build script and you can call any tasks you want .